# How can I use Apache Ignite in Quarkus?

Tags: ignite, quarkus

I am not able to find Apache Ignite dependency in Quarkus or any example where someone is using Apache Ignite with Quarkus. If Quarkus is not currently supporting Apache Ignite then what should be the alternative?

Comment: Have you tried doing that? If you did, please share the results.

Comment: I think you could use any library with Quarkus unless you don´t aim to build the application natively and run it in GraalVM.

Comment: Propose this integration to the Ignite community. You might be able to find community members who will be ready to contribute.

Comment: Yes, by adding simple dependency I am able to run Ignite server using Quarkus.
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this dependency for starting Apache Ignite server using Quarkus.

`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

`

You can Start server by using this line of code.

`

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
```

`And you can stop server by using this line of code`

```
Ignition.stop(true);
```

`

Comment: This works as a non-JEE component :), you need to manage instantiation/destruction of your objects by yourself. When you say supports it means that can be injected into framework standards and lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage ignite by your self. By using CDI factory classes.

```
// Factory class
@Produces
public Ignite createIgnite(){
    return Ignition.start();
}

// Inject in other class
@Inject
private Ignite ignite;
```